# Custom auto-copy in Excel

Tags: excel, auto-increment

I need to create fields that look as follows for an entire year:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-01 00:10:00
2014-01-01 00:20:00
etc.
```

These fields need to be text as I need to match them to similar fields from another spreadsheet. The problem is, when I try the auto-copy function (drag bottom right corner of selection), the following happens:

```
2014-01-01 00:00:00
2014-01-01 00:10:00
2014-01-01 00:20:00
2014-01-01 00:00:01
2014-01-01 00:10:01
2014-01-01 00:20:01
2014-01-01 00:00:02
2014-01-01 00:10:02
2014-01-01 00:20:02
etc.
```

How do I get it to continue incrementing only in 10 minute (in this case, even though the field is text) intervals?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it in a list, but you can make a date in whatever text format you want using `TEXT`

**Option 1**

So, for your other lookups, depending which way they go, you could convert the date field (which auto-increments by 10 minutes nicely) to text in the formula. eg:

```
=VLOOKUP(TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS"),...)
```

**Option 2**

Use a combination of `VALUE` and `TEXT` to give a formula doing the 10 minute increment, but the result as text... So in `A1` have the first actual text date, then use the following formula in the cells below:

```
=TEXT(VALUE(A1)+(10/24/60),"yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS")
```

`VALUE` converts the text date into a real date. `+(10/24/60)` adds 10 minutes and then `TEXT` formats the result back to text.